# Reinstall iPadOS

Tags: ipados

My iPad is misbehaving so I want to do a reinstall of iPadOS.  If I erase all settings, do a fresh install, then restore a iCloud back up will this work?  Or does restoring my backup actually restore the whole lot (inc OS) so it will (potentially) put me back where I started?

I suppose the question is - does an iPadOS iCloud Backup include the OS or just settings/config?

Any/all help is appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS is independent of the data backup, this allows for an updated OS to restore from an older backup - however, restoring a backup *may* reinstall the problem.

Give it a try, see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks - it is at least a place to start :-)